routerlink don't fonctionned when i click into a link like examples pointage-details" i can't go into this link
enter image description here
experiencing issues with the routerLink directive not navigating to the "pointage-details" path as expected
`1. menubar.component.html
  ``'<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z8">     <button (click)="drawer.toggle()" mat-icon-button>         <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>     </button>     <span>Material UI Tutorial</span>     <span class="example-spacer"></span>     <button routerLink="/escales-list" mat-button>Home</button>     <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="lvl1master" mat-button>Master</button>     <mat-menu #lvl1master="matMenu">         <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="company" mat-menu-item>Company</button>         <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="customer" mat-menu-item>Customer</button>         <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="product" mat-menu-item>Product</button>     </mat-menu>      <mat-menu #company="matMenu">         <button mat-menu-item>Term</button>         <button mat-menu-item>Tax</button>         <button mat-menu-item>Currency</button>     </mat-menu>     <mat-menu #customer="matMenu">         <button mat-menu-item>Type</button>         <button mat-menu-item>Tax</button>     </mat-menu>     <mat-menu #product="matMenu">         <button mat-menu-item>Category</button>         <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="variant" mat-menu-item>Variant</button>         <button mat-menu-item>UOM</button>     </mat-menu>      <mat-menu #variant="matMenu">         <button mat-menu-item>Color</button>         <button mat-menu-item>Size</button>     </mat-menu>      <button routerLink="input" mat-button>Input</button>     <button routerLink="autocomplete" mat-button>Autocomplete</button>     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsbmVmB_or8sVLLEq4XhE_A/join" mat-raised-button color="accent">Join Us</a>     <button (click)="badgevisibility()" mat-icon-button>         <mat-icon matBadgeColor="accent" matBadge="15" [matBadgeHidden]="badgevisible" matBadgeSize="small" aria-hidden="false">notifications</mat-icon>     </button>      </mat-toolbar> <mat-drawer-container autosize>     <mat-drawer #drawer opened="true" mode="side" position="start">     <mat-nav-list>         <mat-list-item>             <button routerLink="/dashboard" mat-button><mat-icon>dashboard</mat-icon> Dashboard</button>         </mat-list-item>         <mat-list-item>             <button routerLink="" mat-button><mat-icon>home</mat-icon> Home</button>         </mat-list-item>         <mat-list-item>             <button routerLink="/pointage-details" mat-button><mat-icon>explore</mat-icon> Slider</button>         </mat-list-item>         <mat-list-item>             <button routerLink="/ajouter-pointage" mat-button><mat-icon>table</mat-icon> Table</button>         </mat-list-item>         <mat-list-item>             <button routerLink="/ajouter-pointage" mat-button><mat-icon>settings</mat-icon> Settings</button>         </mat-list-item>         <mat-list-item>             <button mat-button><mat-icon>help</mat-icon> Help</button>         </mat-list-item>         <mat-list-item>             <button mat-button><mat-icon>analytics</mat-icon> analytics</button>         </mat-list-item>     </mat-nav-list>     </mat-drawer>     <mat-drawer-content>         <div style="text-align: center;min-height: 600px;">              <router-outlet></router-outlet>             </div>     </mat-drawer-content> </mat-drawer-container>'` `

2-app.routes.ts
`'import { AjouterPointageComponent } from './ajouter-pointage/ajouter-pointage.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { EscalesListComponent } from './escales-list/escales-list.component';
import { PointageDetailsComponent } from './pointage-details/pointage-details.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'ajouter-pointage', component: AjouterPointageComponent },
{ path: 'escales-list', component: EscalesListComponent },
{ path: 'pointage-details', component: PointageDetailsComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' } // Redirection par défaut vers le dashboard
];
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes ,  { useHash: true})],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { } '
`
3-menubar.component.ts
`'import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menubar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatSidenavModule , MatIconModule , 
    MatDividerModule ,  MatListModule , MatToolbarModule , RouterOutlet , MatMenuModule, MatBadgeModule  ],
  templateUrl: './menubar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './menubar.component.css'
})
export class MenubarComponent {
  badgevisible = false;
  badgevisibility() {
    this.badgevisible = true; }

    
} 

